# How to unit test - zipping a file

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I wrote a simple method that takes in a path to a folder, zips all the content inside that folder, and saves it to a specified destination path.

```
void zipFiles(string sourcePath, string destinationPath, string nameToZipAs)
    {
        try
        {
            // This is where the zip file will be saved.
            string fullDestinationPath = $"{destinationPath}\\{nameToZipAs}";
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(sourcePath, fullDestinationPath);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // ...
        }
}
```

I was wondering how I would go about unit testing this. I read that a unit test shouldn't touch the file system. Is that correct good practice? If so, then I can't create a folder (programmatically) in the unit test in order to zip that folder with my method to verify it works.

Comment: In this case there is tight coupling. ZipFile would have been extensively test by its developers. For testing its interaction with you code you would need to do an integration test. But to test your code in isolation you would need to abstract the zipping process.

Comment: @Nkosi Can you please elaborate when you say "abstract the zipping process" please?

Comment: You would be wrapping the static `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(sourcePath, fullDestinationPath);` behind an abstraction and implementation and then injecting the abstraction as an explicit dependency into the subject under test. This will help decouple your code from static implementation details and help isolate your code.

Comment: [System.IO.Abstractions](https://github.com/System-IO-Abstractions/System.IO.Abstractions) may help

Comment: There are two types of mocking frameworks: constrained and unconstrained. The former: Moq, NSubstitute, FakeItEasy - allow you to fake only virtual members. The latter: TypeMock, JustMock, MS Fakes, Prig, Ionad.Fody, Pose, Harmony, MethodRedirect - allow you to fake anything you want: non-virtual, private and static members, sealed classes and so on. You can use them to mock the `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can unit test the fact that your code calls the `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(...)` method with some specific parameters, if you isolate the code under test properly. If you have VS Enterprise, you can use [MS Fakes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/isolating-code-under-test-with-microsoft-fakes?view=vs-2019). The code below shows a sample NUnit test (dotnet core 3.1) with Fakes Assembly added for System.IO.Compression.ZipFile):

[image: Add Fakes Assembly]

```cs
[Test]
public void ZipFiles_CallsZipFileCreateFromDirectoryWithCorrectArguments()
{
    string sourceDirectoryName = null;
    string destinationArchiveFileName = null;
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        System.IO.Compression.Fakes.ShimZipFile.CreateFromDirectoryStringString = (arg0, arg1) => {
            sourceDirectoryName = arg0;
            destinationArchiveFileName = arg1;
        };

        zipFiles("source", "dest", "zipname");
    }

    Assert.Multiple(() => {
        Assert.AreEqual("source", sourceDirectoryName);
        Assert.AreEqual("dest\\zipname", destinationArchiveFileName);
    });
}
```

The `Fakes\System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.fakes` file in your unit test project should look like this:

```xml
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
  <Assembly Name="System.IO.Compression.ZipFile" Version="4.0.5.0"/>
</Fakes>
```

Finally a link that I highly recommend: [Unit testing best practices with .NET Core and .NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-best-practices)